# Pretty Print for (Informix-)4gl code

Tags: informix, pretty-print, 4gl

i'm searching for a pretty print program (script, code, whatever) for Informix-4GL sources.

Do you know any ? Than you, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the IIUG (International Informix User Group) [software](http://www.iiug.org/software) archive?  There are two pretty printers there (of indeterminate quality).

The other place to look would be the [Aubit4GL](http://aubit4gl.sf.net/) site - an open source variant of I4GL.  Again, I'm not sure that they have a pretty-printer, but it might be something they have (though a casual check doesn't show one).

Comment: yes i checked them all before, but they are all VERY basic. I look for a good indention output.

Comment: OK - fair enough.  I've not used either of them seriously, or looked at them for a long time.  It would help if you'd said what you had looked at.

Comment: Just curious, what do you use informix4gl for? I use informix 4gl too, maybe thats why am interested.

Comment: @gath: if you're asking me, I'm the architect for I4GL, though the development team is in India.  I use I4GL to give me topics for presentations at user conferences.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is reading this post anymore, but the easiest way to get some kind of nice "pretty print" of 4gl code is to view it in the Openedge Developer Studio, then use ctrl-I to set indention.  You can adjust indention in the editor settings by saying the length of "tabs". (default is 4, I use 3)
Then do a ctrl-shift-f to make all command words uppercase.

Next, you can condense the code a few lines by moving all the "DO:" statements up a line next to the "THEN" statement with this regular expression search and replace.
ctrl-f:
search "\s*\n\s*DO[:]"
replace " DO:"
make sure you click the checkbox marked regular expressions.

At this point the code is nice and tidy.
Do a ctrl-a and ctrl-c to copy it to the clipboard.
paste it in Outlook as an email without sending.  Print it in color.